# Create Merge Request Not Working in Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I just pushed a new branch "TEST" and Gitlab has the button to create a new merge request.  When I click it though, it takes me to a page that asks me to select the source, and what it should be merged into.

The problem is the only branch in the source is master.  The TEST branch is not there.

I can however see the TEST branch on the branches tab on the repository page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I experienced exactly the same problem today, and found the workaround that works perfectly for me:
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4100#issuecomment-18669303

This issue is around caching branch lists in redis, disabling cache in the code fixes it.

```
diff --git a/app/models/repository.rb b/app/models/repository.rb
index daf1765..ff683e6 100644
--- a/app/models/repository.rb
+++ b/app/models/repository.rb
@@ -34,9 +34,9 @@ class Repository
   end

   def branch_names
-    Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key(:branch_names)) do
+#    Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key(:branch_names)) do
       raw_repository.branch_names
-    end
+#    end
   end

   def tag_names
```

Comment: That did the trick.  I had restarted gitlab and redis.  Additionally I did a hard refresh on my browser and it showed up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another option that works is to go to Repository -> Branches and if the branch is there (as it should not rely on cache on this page), you can press Merge request, which should work.

Also what helped me was creating random branch, which refreshes the cache and you can create the MR through the regular way. Don't forget to remove the branch afterwards.